# Linearize a constraint

Tags: linear-programming, mixed-integer-programming, linearization

I have intermediate knowledge of optimization and mathematical modeling
I have this constraint. I know how to model it with integers (which leads to a mixed-integer linear program). However,I was wondering if there is a way to avoid integer variables.

let: 
$x_1, x_2$ have undefined signal, they can be positive or negative, but both of them are bounded by an upper and lower limit
$$
x_1 = x_{1}^+ + x_1^-\\
\underline{x}_1 \lt x_1 \lt \bar{x}_1 
\\ \underline{x}_1 \le x_1^- \le 0, \quad \quad 0 \le x_1^+ \le \bar{x}_1 
$$ similarly $$
\\ x_2 = x_2^+ + x_2^-
\\ \underline{x}_2 \lt x_2 \lt \bar{x}_2 
\\ \underline{x}_2 \le x_2^- \le 0, \quad \quad 0 \le x_2^+ \le \bar{x}_2 
$$

These above are just definitions.
Now what I want to do is:
$$
x_1 \times x_2 \ge 0
$$
which basically means: $x_1$ and $x_2$ must have the same sign or be zero 
Another way to describe this constraint is or:
$$
x_1^+ > 0 \Rightarrow x_2^- = 0
\\ x_2^+ > 0 \Rightarrow x_1^- = 0
$$

I know how to do it with auxiliary integer variables; I was trying to avoid integers in my formulation to continue using a QP or an LP solver.

I tried a big-M constraints and failed. I mention it here to show my work, and save you the effort of exploring it:
$$
x_1^- +M\cdot x_2^+ \le 0
$$
This is wrong because it forces $x_2^+$ to be always $0$, even when $x_1^-=0$

$$
\frac{x_1^-}{\underline{x}_1} -\frac{x_2^+}{\bar{x_2}} \le 0
$$
Normalize both variables to handle a percentage, or a surrogate between 0 and 1. Not effective either because it allows $x_2^+$ to be near its upper bound, while $x_1^-$ is slightly below zero.

Comment: https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linearization

Comment: Do you have an objective function? It often helps making constraints easier. Small example: constraint: $2x_1+x_2=8$. It is difficult to find a unique solution. But with max $x_1+x_2$ it is obvious that the (optimal) solution is $(x_1,x_2)=(0,8)$

Comment: The cost function is quite complicated and large; these 2 variables and the constraint I'm talking about are a part of a large optimization problem.
What I can tell you, though, is that the cost function is quadratic; I am using GUROBI's QP solver

It has just occurred to me that I can achieve my goal with two auxiliary variables, and a penalty on their product.
I will explain this in a separate answer below

Answer (score 0):

It has just occurred to me that I can achieve my goal with a penalty on their product.

$$
Penalty = M\cdot(-x_2^- \times x_1^+)
$$

Where $M$ is large enough. Doesn't this qualify as a quadratic cost term?

Comment: It appears that this cost term corresponds to a Q matrix which is NOT positive-semidefinite. I guess I have to go with auxiliary integer variables